# My Google Chrome is not opening on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

Some beautiful day my chrome decide to not open. When I try to open on terminal the following message is shown:

> [18613:18613:0524/124744.412535:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
> Trace/breakpoint trap (imagem do núcleo gravada)

All solutions I found on web was from 2015 ~ 2018, still I've tried:

- Reinstall Chrome many times
- Reinstall previous version from Chrome
- Reinstall the package `gnome-keyring`
- Run with flags to disable GPU and other errors happen.

Someone has any other solution?

Comment: Try to run `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome` in terminal.

Comment: OMG it works! Thanks @yangmandi